# Load div if string equals

Tags: jquery

I would like to load a particular div if a string within another div is specified.

My HTML:

```
<div id="string1">Apples</div>
<div id="string2">Oranges</div>
```

It doesn't have to be dynamic or ajax or anything. Just when the page loads, it looks at what the string in #string is, and then loads/shows a corresponding  depending on what the string was.

```
if string1 eq 'apples' load('.apples')
if string2 eq 'oranges' load('.apples')
```

Using the logic above ^

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's must be unique in page.

```
// jQuery
$('#string2').toggle($('#string1').text() == 'Apples');

if ($('#string1').text() == 'Apples' || $('#string2').text() == 'Oranges') {
    load('.apples');
}

// JS
document.getElementByID('#string2').style = 'display: ' + (document.getElementByID('#string1').innerHTML == 'Apples');
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post to reflect this. Any help with my original question?

Comment: @Teebling Check updated answer. I don't know what your `load` function does, so I hope you can implement it on your own